# linux kernel updates but not effective

Tags: kernel, updates, kde

Software update doesn't finish normal and aborts with an error and doesn't report the problem, clicking on details returns blank. KDE's UI doesn't provide the option to view details when the update progresses (in the simulated terminal environment). Checking the following commands seems updates are saved but why the effective version number is lower than the downloaded packages?

```
$ uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic

$ sudo apt-get install linux-generic
[sudo] password for hamid:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.53.56).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.58.0 libboost-serialization1.58.0 linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-34
  linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-36 linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-38 linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-42 linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-47
  linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I upgraded to 16.10 and this is the result:$ uname -r 
4.4.0-21-generic

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with grub settings. Using [GRUB Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) I set it to load the latest kernel and everything is running as should. And of course it was possible to check updates via apt commands but problem was the error in software update occurred in the GUI and the afterwards checking in the command prompt showed no traces - a catch 22!